# How to do Google test for function which are not a part of class?

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, googletest

Am performing Google test, Here am facing one challenge.

In my project some of the functions are not included in the header file, they are directly included in the source file. I can access the functions which are in header file by creating obj of the class but am not able to access which are only in source file.

Please guide me how to access these function.

Thanks in advance!.
Kiran JP

Comment: kindly explore EXPECT_CALL. i think it can help

Comment: A bit unclear whats your problem! You get a compile error from your test code, because your function is not declared -> simply declare with extern or even better: Write a header which have the prototypes in it! If available, simply include in your test code file. You want to know that a function will be called? Take a look at EXPECT_CALL. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare them extern in your test code.

Example. Let's say you have a source file like this:

```cpp
// Function declared and defined in .cpp file
void myFunction() {
    // implementation
}
```

Then you could go ahead and do the following in your test code:

```cpp
extern void myFunction();

TEST(MyTest) {
    myFunction();
}
```

Unless the function was explicitly declared with internal linkage. Either by declaring it static or by declaring/defining it inside an anonymous namespace in C++11 or above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...
I did the same as mentioned above but am getting facing error like "Undfined reference to"...Detailed error is mention below.

"undefined reference to `CalculateCRC16(unsigned char*, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: How is the function declared inside the original source file? Is it declared static maybe? Or inside an anonymous namespace? Or maybe in a different namespace? Also, are you sure you're linking against the lib of the source project?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the declaration of those functions to a header file, either to your existing header files, or to a new header file.

For example, say you have this function in your `class.cc` file without any declaration in `class.h` file:

```
int SomeFunction(int a, int b){
  //...
}
```

You should add the following line to a header file. Let's call it `header.h`:

```
// header.h
int SomeFunction(int a, int b);
```

Then modify your test file to include `header.h`:

```
#include "header.h"

TEST(SomeFunction, Test1) {
    int c = SomeFunction(1,2);
}
```